# How to obtain the text value from the current clicked div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have for arguments sake, 5 dynamically generated div elements, which are rows in my page. They are all of the same class type but have different text values. How can I read the string value of the selected div element using jquery. Is it possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We need some code here.   Generally speaking, if its a 1-to-1 map you can pull a list of elements (array) then get the [n]th element's HTML (innerHTML) to get the value.  But I am just guessing at what you want.  Without some code its hard to figure a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function call on click for div's with same class:

```
<div class="some_class">
bgfdbdgf
</div>
Javascript:
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.some_class').on('click', function(){
console.log($(this).text());
})
});
```